# How to adjust seewave spectro to account for hydrophone sensitivity?

Tags: calibration, spectrogram, db, seewave

I am using seewave's spectro() to generate a spectrogram from a hydrophone recording.  My call is:

```
spectro(wave, wl=2048, wn="hamming", ovlp=50, flim=c(40, 1000), dBref=3D1*10e-6, scalelab="dB re 1 uPa", palette=temp.colors, collevels=seq(10, 100))
```

My question: how do I alter the spectrogram to make it display amplitude
colors based on the calibrated dB for my hydrophone?  I am using a
soundtrap, with an end-to-end calibration factor of 175.9 dB.  If dB are
set to "max0" then I would add 175.9 to each amplitude measurement to get a
calibrated amplitude, but I'm not sure how to do that with spectro.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You set dBref=10**(-175.9/20). (use the R equivalent of potentiating)

internally, spectro does the following operation

```
if(!is.null(dB))
    {
        if(is.null(dBref)) {z <- 20*log10(z)} else {z <- 20*log10(z/dBref)}
    ...
    }
```

So, it divides the data values by dBref. Consequently this is equivalent to adding 175.9 dB to your levels.